# One view to do everything or a different view per page?

Tags: 6, views

If I need to display the last 10 nodes created on my front page regardless of content type and need to do the same in my sub-pages but need to filter by specific content type, is it easier to create several different views or to create one view that does all of that? If I need to create one view, how would I restrict different pages to specific content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I create a view per content type and set up decent defaults and then have displays to handle the different uses.  Special pages and other one offs (like the home page in your case) have specific views.

I find this approach better handles changes that may come down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly have one view for the home page that displays everything, and then another view that uses the current node type as an argument?

Assuming that is that when you're on a *blog* node type (for example) you want to display the most recent *blog* type nodes.